# is this good way to find 3 month older record

Tags: php, postgresql

please take a look at mycode

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT u.*,age(u.created_on) older FROM users u")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    preg_match("#(.*?)([0-9]+)(\s)mons(.*?)#is", $row->older, $match);
    if (isset($match[2]) && $match[2] == "3") {
        echo "{$row->email} is 3 month older";
    }
}
```

i know this can be done in one query only

you can post alternate solution to this or can improve my code.

i want to check here that i am doing it correct or not

Comment: if no then post another solution !

Comment: Attempt something first. SO is not a *"hey redo this for me even though I know it can be done better, but I have not bothered to try."* site.

Comment: no problem , i got the answer see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to get records older than three months you can write query like this :

```
select * from "table" WHERE dstart < current_date - INTERVAL '3 month'
```

Comment: you may be posted mysql query but i am using postgres

Comment: @user2907171  check now the query.

Comment: i updated with my requirement `select * from users WHERE DATE(created_on) = DATE(NOW())-INTERVAL '3 month'` but i got the error

Comment: ok problem with ` character . thanks i got the solution